# What is the JavaFX TableView's method equivalent to JTable.getSelectedRow()

Tags: jtable, javafx-2, tableview

I need it to access the information inside a tableview in my program so I can display a window (stage) with more information of the elements in the selected rows of the table. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get selected item from table use next code:

```
table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()
```

selection model also has other convenience methods to provide info about index, multiple selection, etc.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I had a hard time looking for this because most of the topics I would find would adress the editing of cells, not the "getting" of those elements.